# I am getting an error when using xaml for a xamarin forns project and I am getting an exception occurred while rendering the control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpGvK.png)I am making an app that simply request a url using a button, and I want to display the contents of the url on a WebView which is not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SAT"
             x:Class="SAT.MainPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 BackgroundColor="#3C3838">
        <Button Text="On\\Off" 
                BackgroundColor="#6FD761"
                Margin="70,240,70,0"
                x:Name="ToggleRelay1"
                Clicked="ToggleRelay1_Clicked"/>

        <Button Text="On\\Off" 
                BackgroundColor="#6FD761"
                Margin="70,20,70,0"
                x:Name="TggleRelay2"
                Clicked="TggleRelay2_Clicked"/>

        <Button Text="Having Trouble ? connect Manualy" 
                BackgroundColor="#00D06262"
                Margin="0,250,0,0"/>

    </StackLayout>
    <WebView x:Name="TestWebView"
             HeightRequest="100"
             WidthRequest="100"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code behind in MainPage.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 1):

ContentPage does not support multiple items. Consider putting the web view into the StackLayout or (if you need the buttons to overlay web view) use the AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: I have tried to put the WebView inside the StackLayout and I am sorry to say it is still giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

Content Page can only have one direct child so your xaml code should look like this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SAT"
         x:Class="SAT.MainPage">

<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
             BackgroundColor="#3C3838">
    <Button Text="On\\Off" 
            BackgroundColor="#6FD761"
            Margin="70,240,70,0"
            x:Name="ToggleRelay1"
            Clicked="ToggleRelay1_Clicked"/>

    <Button Text="On\\Off" 
            BackgroundColor="#6FD761"
            Margin="70,20,70,0"
            x:Name="TggleRelay2"
            Clicked="TggleRelay2_Clicked"/>

    <Button Text="Having Trouble ? connect Manualy" 
            BackgroundColor="#00D06262"
            Margin="0,250,0,0"/>



<WebView x:Name="TestWebView"
         HeightRequest="100"
         WidthRequest="100"/>
    </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage>
```

Comment: I have just tried you code adjustment and it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Umm try putting this stacklayout in contentpage.content tag

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what do you mean

Comment: I read the error message and it says that you have a property called `thisActivity `which is null do you know where this is?

Comment: No idea what is that, I got nothing called thisActivity

Comment: Can you add the whole error stacktrace into a text file or just as code here that would help!